# Sharepoint 2010 Timer job works only manually

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, file, custom-timer-job, network

I have 2 Sharepoint timer job, in production environment, (WFE server and Application server) that read files from a server folder and make different treatments of the files.

The timer job 1:
 daily, at start time / no later than 12am when I see the log I have this error message :

```
 System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.      
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     
 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath,
 Boolean bFromProxy)     
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)   
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)    
 at SharePoint.Common.Utilities.SpreadsheetCreator.UpdateTemplates(String rootSiteUrl)
```

and in the Central admin the status was : succeeded

so I run it manually and it works(duration 2h30).
Then I decided to change the time start 2 am / no later than 4am

in the log I have this error:

```
System.IO.IOException: The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security. Please ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you.   
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)  
at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles,  Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption) 
at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)    
at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path)  
at SharePoint.Common.Utilities.SpreadsheetCreator.BackupOldExcelTemplateFiles(String rootFolder)  
at SharePoint.Common.Utilities.SpreadsheetCreator.UpdateTemplates(String rootSiteUrl)
```

For the timer job 2:
Hourly
in the Central admin the status was : succeeded for each hour (at night)
but 0second duration
so I run it manually or I wait when I am logged and it execute the code perfectly.

I made restart OWSTIMER.exe and iisreset for both servers, with no luck
PS : the 2 timer job worked perfectly since 3 years, this problem only begin to happen, when I deploy new wsp (only new webparts, no change in timer job)
Help me please to understand the issue.